# Trouble printing the total revenue

Tags: c#

I'm suppose to be writing a program in C# where you enter the amount of tickets sold, and how much revenue they generated based on each ticket class (A, B, and C). Then it should add all three revenue amounts together, which I'm having an issue with.

I'm only getting one error and that is

> "CS1061   'int' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no
>   accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type
>   'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)"

Basically, when i run my code everything works except it doesn't add all three revenue amounts together at the end.

Here's my code:

```cs
private void calculateRevenueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        // user input totals
        int classAtickets;
        int classBtickets;
        int classCtickets;
        classAtickets = int.Parse(classASold.Text);
        classBtickets = int.Parse(classBSold.Text);
        classCtickets = int.Parse(classCSold.Text);



        // cost of tickets
        int classAcost = 15;
        int classBcost = 12;
        int classCcost = 9;

        //names and how to calculate
        int classatotal;
        int classbtotal;
        int classctotal;

        classatotal = classAtickets * classAcost;
        classbtotal = classBtickets * classBcost;
        classctotal = classCtickets * classCcost;

        classARevenue.Text = classatotal.ToString("c");
        classBRevenue.Text = classbtotal.ToString("c");
        classCRevenue.Text = classctotal.ToString("c");


        //how to calculate
        int totalRev;
        totalRev = classatotal + classbtotal + classctotal;

        totalRev.Text = totalRev.ToString("c");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `totalRev` variable is of type `int`, which is just an integer number, and you are trying to assign a value to its `Text` property, which does not exist.

Judging from the rest of your code, you probably meant to specify the name of some field, like the `classASold` and `classARevenue` fields before it, instead of the name of the `totalRev` variable.

To fix it, either change `totalRev` in the last line to the name of the appropriate field, or create a new field for it if it does not exist.